# Add WhereParameters to LinqDataSource in Selecting event

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have a repeater using a LinqDataSource as a data source. When a query string is entered, I'd like to filter the results, but ONLY when a query string is entered. If there is no query string, the results should not be filtered, all results should be returned.

I'm trying to add a WhereParameter to my LinqDataSource in the Selecting event of the LinqDataSource, but it's not working.  Here's my code:

```
protected void ldsImages_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
{
    if (Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
    {
        e.WhereParameters.Add("ImageTypeID", Request.QueryString["id"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: _How_ is it not working? Wrong results returned, runtime exception, no results returned etc.

Comment: @Cornelius - it doesn't filter the results, it just returns all the results.

Comment: Need to see your LinqDataSource declaration to diagnose

Answer (score 3):

Adding an onload event to handle the LinqDataSource_*_Load() to the LinqDataSource seems to let you to do the following:

```
protected void ldsAssets_Draft_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    string Where_Statement = " Planner_ID == @Planner_ID";
    ldsAssets_Draft.WhereParameters.Add("Planner_ID", System.Data.DbType.Int32, User_ID.ToString());
    if (this._DraftOrderStatus != BusinessLogic.DraftOrderStatus.All) {
        Where_Statement += " AND Status_ID == @Status_ID";
        ldsAssets_Draft.WhereParameters.Add("Status_ID", System.Data.DbType.Int32, ((int)this._DraftOrderStatus).ToString());
    }
    ldsAssets_Draft.Where = Where_Statement;
}
```

Since it's called on the load of the object, and not the selecting--you can still use your  object with out much code behind.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure the Request.QueryString["id"] value is not null?

Are you setting the AutoGenerateWhereClause property to "true" on your LinqDataSource?

Read the [Remarks section of the WhereParameters documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasourceselecteventargs.whereparameters.aspx) carefully.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used a LinqDataSource, but could you not query your results as shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.selecting.aspx)?
(Code extract from the site):

```
 protected void LinqDataSource_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        var cities = from city in citiesArray
                     where city.CompareTo("B") > 0
                     select city;
        e.Result = cities;

    }
```

Therefore, you'd have something like:

```
 protected void LinqDataSource_Selecting(object sender, LinqDataSourceSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        if(Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
        {
               var myImage = from img in imageSource
                             where img.ID == Request.QueryString["id"]
                             select img;
               e.Result = myImage;
        }
        else
        {
               e.Result = imageSource;
        }


    }
```

A few things to note. First, this is untested :D. Second, if your ID is an integer, don't forget to cast the querystring as an integer. Finally, you should be sanitizing the querystring before using it. Although it may not be a major problem here, it's good practise.

Answer (score 0):

In the markup for the `LinqDataSource` you still need to declare the parameter in the `Where` property of the `asp:LinqDataSource` tag.

Example:

```
<asp:LinqDataSource ID="LDS_Images" runat="server" 
    ContextTypeName="DataContext" TableName="ImagesTable" 
    Where="ImageTypeID == @ImageTypeID ...>
 ...
</asp:LinqDataSource>
```